# The number of calls to receptionist per one hour has Poisson distribution with mean 1.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

The number of calls to receptionist per one hour has Poisson distribution with mean $1$. Find c.d.f for time $T$ of the arrival call if it is known that at the end of the second hour there is only one call arrived.

Let $X$ be the number of calls in an hour, then $X$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $1$, Let $Y$ be the waiting time for a call (in hours). $Y$ has an exponential distribution. But how to get to $T$ and use the given condition?

Comment: A Poisson process is memoryless, I believe, meaning the condition is probably a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to arrive at the answer, and some can be very short . I assume you would like to have a somewhat detailed analysis.

Denote the waiting time of the $i$-th call as $T_i$, and you already know that $T_i$ are iid with exponential density. Among this list of infinitely many $T_i$, only the first two are relevant to the given condition of having observed 1 call.

Denote the critical time length "up to the end of second hour" as $t_c$ to illustrate how it works generally. Here $t_c = 2$.

$$P_c \equiv \mathrm{Pr}\{\, \text{exactly one call within}~t_c \,\} = \mathrm{Pr}\{\, T_1 < t_c \quad \& \quad T_1 + T_2 > t_c \,\} \tag*{Eq.(1)} $$
If you've never done this, it's important that you go ahead and set up a double integral with the exponential density, and in the end this probability should be exactly the discrete Poisson distribution with the relevant parameter $\mathrm{Pois}[t_c]$.

We will be doing a very similar double integrall for the conditional CDF, thus I'll omit this one. Here let me restore the explicit rate $\lambda$ (which numeric value is 1 here). See the appendix for the related discussion.

$$P_c = e^{-\lambda t_c} \frac{ (\lambda t_c)^k }{ k! }\Bigg|_{k = 1} = \lambda t_c e^{-\lambda t_c} $$

Now, the objective is to find the CDF of the form $\mathrm{Pr}\{\, T_1 < t_1 \,\}$, and we want it to be conditioned so it will be a division

$$F(t_1) \equiv \mathrm{Pr}\{\, T_1 < t_1 ~\big|\quad T_1 < t_c ~ \& ~ T_1 + T_2 > t_c\,\} = \frac{ P_1 }{ P_c }~, \qquad P_1 \equiv \mathrm{Pr}\{\, T_1 < t_1 ~ \& ~ T_1 + T_2 > \color{blue}{t_c}\,\}$$

Please compare $P_1$ and $P_c$ and understand what they have in common and how they are different.

Let me use the dummy variable $u$ for $T_1$ in the double integral and, again, the explicit rate $\lambda$ (some people use the scale parameter $\beta = \frac1{\lambda}$. It's just a matter of bookkeeping):

$$\begin{align*}
P_1 &= \int_{u=0}^{u = t_1} \left[ \,f_{T_1}(u) \int_{t_2 = 0}^{t_2 = t_c - u} f_{T_2}(t_2)\, \mathrm{d}t_2 \right] \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \int_{u=0}^{u = t_1} \left[ \,\lambda e^{-\lambda u} \int_{t_2 = 0}^{t_2 = t_c - u} \lambda e^{-\lambda t_2}\, \mathrm{d}t_2 \right] \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \int_{u=0}^{u = t_1} \Big[ \, \lambda e^{-\lambda u} \cdot e^{-\lambda (t_c - u)}\, \Big] \,\mathrm{d}u \\
&= e^{-\lambda t_c} \int_{u=0}^{u = t_1} \lambda \,\mathrm{d}u \\
&= \lambda t_1 e^{-\lambda t_c}
\end{align*}$$

That is, the CDF is linear (the rate $\lambda$ cancels) and the density is uniform.
$$F(t_1) = \frac{ t_1 }{ t_c } ~,\qquad f(t_1) = \frac{ \mathrm{d} F(t_1) }{ \mathrm{d} t_1 } = \frac1{t_c} \tag*{, for $0 < t_1 < t_c$}$$

This well-known property of the simple Poisson process is trivial yet profound, and it can be easily generalized to "given that $n$ events occurred in a specified interval, the waiting time of the events follow a $n$ dimensional uniform distribution over the $n$-simplex".

btw, here your $t_c = 2$ is 2 hours, if it matters.

---

**Appendix: the parameter of Poisson distribution**

The probability mass function of the discrete Poisson distribution  in its full form (in the context of a simple Poisson process) is
$$\mathrm{Pr}\{\, X = k \,\} = e^{ -\lambda t} \frac{ (\lambda t)^k }{ k! }$$
where $\lambda$ is the rate and $t$ is size of the "space" of interest. Here $\lambda = \frac1{\text{hour}} = \frac{60}{\text{minute}}$ so if you're looking at an interval (space) of $t = \text{one hour}$, then your Poisson distribution has mean $\lambda t = 1$. If you're looking at an interval of $t = \text{13 minutes}$, then your Poisson distribution has mean $\lambda t = \frac{60}{13}$.

Answer (score 0):

For a Poisson process $N(t)$ with rate $\lambda$, conditioned on $\{N(t)=n\}$ the arrivals $(T_1,\ldots, T_n)$ have the same joint distribution as the order statistics corresponding to $n$ independent random variables uniformly distributed on $(0,t)$ - this is a well-known result that @Lee David Chung Lin mentioned in their answer.

So conditioned on $\{N(2)=1\}$, we see here that the time $T$ of the arrival is uniformly distributed over $(0,2)$.